# Angular redirect to parameter in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router

I have some lazy loaded routes as following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':lang',
        loadChildren: './components/home/home.module#HomeModule',
        // redirectTo: "en"
    },
    {
        path: ':id/customers',
        loadChildren: './components/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'products',
        loadChildren: './components/products/products.module#ProductsModule'
    }
];
```

When I open the page with this url: `http://localhost:4200/en` it works fine. But the user doesn't know to add `en` parameter to the url, so the page doesn't load without parameter. So, I must redirect it to `/en`. But when I use `redirectTo: "en"` I get the following errors:

```
Error: Invalid configuration of route ':lang': redirectTo and loadChildren cannot be used together
```

I found something about this error, but doesn't relate to my case. Any idea?

Comment: When do you want to redirect to /en? Is it when the user is already on /en or on another language route (/fr for example)? No. So redirectTo must not be set on the ':lang' route. It must be set on another route with an empty path. That's when the user should be redirected to /en.

Comment: @JBNizet No, when the user opens domain.com, I want to redirect to domain.com/en. Thanks. setting it to another route with an empty path make it work.

Comment: @JBNizet If you would post your comment as an answer, I could accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting redirectTo on the route `:lang` means: if the user is on that route, it should be redirected to `/en`. That's not what you want. You want to redirect the user to `/en`when the path is the root path. So you need to add an empty path route and redirect from there:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/en',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a conflict in your route bewteen :lang and :id.

Can you try:

```
theObjectOfYourIds/:id/customers
```

and

```
languages/:lang
```

And for your problem,

You can't have a redirectTo with a loaChildren.

If you want to go to 'en', do the strategy inside your components (`app.component.ts` for example).